# Airflow how to perform an Operator for each item in a dynamically calculated list?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is there a way to perform an airflow *operator* for each item in a non-hard-coded list? For each item in a dynamically calculated list (result of a `@task`) want to run a docker image, passing in the item as an environment variable:

```
for item in list_fetched_from_a_task:
    run docker container passing in the item as a environment variable
```

This DAG will print each item in a list result of a sql query:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook


@task
def get_all_items():
    mssqlServer = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id="my_mssql")
    raw_item_names = mssqlServer.get_records(
        """
        use database_name;
        select itemName from database_name.fds.items;
        """
    )

    item_names = []
    for item_name in raw_item_names:
        item_names.append(item_name[0])
    
    return item_names # ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

@task
def do_thing_for_one_item(single_item):
    print("Doing thing for item: " + single_item)


with DAG(dag_id="do-thing-for-each-item-process", start_date=datetime(2022, 10, 29)) as dag:
    do_thing_for_one_item.expand(single_item=get_all_items())
```

But what if you wanted to run a `DockerOperator` to run an image for each item in that list? Passing in `single_item` item as an environment variable to the image? Like an Airflow Operator's equivalent to the `.expand(List)` method that would run the operator for each item in the provided list?

Something like this (pseudo code):

```py
for single_item in list_fetched_from_task:
    do DockerOperator(
        task_id='run-some-image-for-single-item',
        image='some-image:latest',
        docker_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='host',
        environment={
            "SINGLE_item": single_item
        },
        dag=dag
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `DockerOperator` in a `PythonOperator`, and pass in the result (XCom) from the task that creates the list:

```py
@task()
def run_docker_container(context, list_fetched_from_task):
    for single_item in list_fetched_from_task:
        DockerOperator(
            task_id='run-some-image-for-single-item',
            image='some-image:latest',
            docker_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock',
            network_mode='host',
            environment={
                "SINGLE_item": single_item
            },
        ).execute(context=context)
```

You won't have this rendered in the UI, as it's impossible for the Airflow Webserver to know how many tasks it is going to run ahead of time.